# Maximum amount of tasks running in parallel?

Tags: java, algorithm, scala, priority-queue

**The problem:**

> We are given a set of n tasks, each having an integer start time and
>   end time. What is the maximum amount of tasks running in parallel at
>   any given time?
>
> The algorithm should run in **O(n log n)** time.

This is a school assignment so i don't need a direct answer but any code snippets are welcome as long as they are in Java or Scala (assignment supposed to be written in scala.)

Some of the hints say that i should take advantage of Priority queues. I read the documentation, but I'm not really sure on how to use them, so any code snippets are welcome.

The input data could for instance be `Array[Pair[Int,Int]] = Array((1000,2000),(1500,2200))` and so on.

I'm really struggling to set the Ordering of the priority queue, so if nothing else i hope someone could help me with that.

*PS:
The priority queue is supposed to be initialized with PriorityQueue()(ord).*

**Edit: i came up with the solution using priority queues but thank you for all the answers. You guys helped me figure out the logic!**

Comment: Assume that you have the tasks in two lists (one sorted by start time, the other by end time) and you maintain indices for the "current" task in each of them. Then you know the time when the next start and the next end occurs. So you just have to walk through the arrays simultaneously and remember the maximum. You could do similarly with two priority queues, but this is probably slower than sorted arrays (that's just a guess, you would need to measure to be sure).

Comment: @NicoSchertler If i go trough the sorted arrays simultaneously wont the algorithm run in linear time?

Comment: Yes, but you have to sort first. Hence, n log n.

Comment: @NicoSchertler okay thank you! Do you know about the count method in scala (i imagine it's the same in java)? Is it fast/slow?  :)

Comment: I guess, it won't help you much. Don't know how it is implemented, but it has probably similar performance as a simple for loop.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Oh yeah, thanks i figured it out! :)

Answer (score 2):

**Soln without using Priority Queue.**

Consider the array of tasks as follows:

```
[(1,2), (1,5), (2,4), ....]   // (a,b) : (start_time, end_time)
```

**Step 1** : Construct an array considering `start_time` and `end_time` together.

```
[1,2,1,5,2,4....]
```

**Step 2** : Maintain another array to know whether the time at index i is start_time or end_time

```
 [S,E,S,E,S,E...] // S:Start_Time, E:End_Time
```

**Step 3** : Sort the first array. And make sure to change the index in another array accordingly.

**Step 4** : Maintain two variables, `parallel_ryt_now` and `max_parallel_till_now`. And traverse the second array as follows:

```
for i in 1:len(second_array):
   if(second_array[i] == "S"):
        parallel_ryt_now ++
   else
        parallel_ryt_now -- 
   if parallel_ryt_now > max_parallel_till_now:
          max_parallel_till_now = parallel_ryt_now
```

**Logic :**

While traversing the sorted array, when u encounter a `start_time`, that means a task has started. Thus increment the the `parallel_ryt_now` and when u encounter an `end_time`, means that a task has completed, thus decrement the `parallel_ryt_now`.

This way, at every moment the `parallel_ryt_now` var stores the parallel running tasks.

**Time Complexity** = Sort + Traverse = `O(nlogn) + O(n)` = `O(nlogn)`

**Space Complexity** = `O(n)` (To store the extra array for info about whether time at index `i` is `start_time` or `end_time` )

I hope it helped.

Comment: If you make sure that all `E` tags are before all `S` tags for the same time, then this is a great way to do it. So better sort one array with a struct or similarly.

Comment: For any task, `E` >= `S`. So any way we can indentify them

Comment: I mean the scenario when for some point in time `t`, there are some tasks that end at `t` and some tasks start at `t`. You don't want to count them all.

Comment: Oh Yeah, Nice Point. I think that can be handled.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I used priority queues in my solution which now works, but your answer helped me understand the logic ! :)